# Power shell script to get states for app pool

Tags: powershell, iis, window

help me to rewrite PowerShell script to get the status for IIS app pool on windows 7 and windows 2008 (IIS6).

```
function Get-AppPool {

    [CmdletBinding()]

    param
    (

    [string[]]$Server,
    [String]$Pool

    )

#region loadAssembly 

[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.Web.Administration')

#endregion loadAssembly

foreach ($s in $server)

{

$sm = [Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager]::OpenRemote($s)

$apppools = $sm.ApplicationPools["$pool"]

$status = $apppools.state


        $info = @{
        'Pool Name'=$pool;
        'Status'=$status;
        'Server'=$S;
        }

        Write-Output (New-Object –Typename PSObject –Prop $info)

        }

    }
```

Comment: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-ScriptFunction-2ed89388#content not working in windows 7

Comment: why isnt it working?

Comment: i don't know .i think it's not support win 7

Comment: no error but no out put

Comment: you should share your script with us

Comment: Did you read the question and the answer on the "Q and A"-Tab for the given link?

Comment: Do you need that script to get the application pool state of the current machine or for remote also?

Comment: Also, how do you try to call it?

Comment: .\Get-AppPool.ps1 -Server localhost  -Pool DefaultAppPool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to get the state of an application pool from the current machine, try this:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
Get-WebAppPoolState -Name 'DefaultAppPool'
```

Comment: are you serious? I asked you whether you need the state for the current machine or for remote also... I think your question is answered